# coolpad note 3 not starting

Tags: backup, coolpad-note-3

- I was trying to install **8676-I02 6.0 V22** Marshmallow  update on my **Coolpad Note 3**.
- I installed the Drivers on my laptop with **Windows 7 Ultimate**, the drivers were installed successfully. I haven't attached the phone to the laptop while installing drivers.
- Then i tried to backup nvram as described below:

  - Created file **nvram.img**
  - Clicked on **readback** button
  - Powered Off my phone, and attached it to the laptop, laptop showed installing drivers.
  - SP Flash Tool showed the **Green Circle**.
  - I found that nvram.img was created.

After closing SP Flash Tool, and disconnecting USB cable, I've tried to Power-On the phone, but it did not Power-Up, there is no charging sign, the phone is not showing anything.

I had not enabled USB debugging. so please help regarding this issue.

Comment: Have you updated the **8676-I02 6.0 V22** rom with **Download** or **Firmware Upgarde** button? or just you have used readback button only?

Comment: Does your phone have a non removable battery?